# Не могу указать компилятор в Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Скачал с официального сайта сборку,  и не могу указать компилятор в стандартном комплекте (скрины прилагаются).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и если запустить проект с этим комплектом, то, естественно "Укажите компилятор для комплекта в настройках проекта".

В стандартном комплекте (был сразу создан) не указан отладчик и компилятор, и указать их нельзя, он их не видит.

Я создал новый комплект *Main* и указал там компилятор *MSVS* (У меня установлена *Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013*). Пробую запустить с моим комплектом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Qt* не видит комплекта, потому что нужен профиль. Указываю его:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И компиляция останавливается на шаге 1/2 и в консоль сборки такие ошибки...

```
21:11:07: Выполняются этапы для проекта untitled14...
21:11:07: Настройки не изменились, этап qmake пропускается.
21:11:07: Запускается: «C:\Qt\Qt5.4.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe» 
    C:\Qt\Qt5.4.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc /Fddebug\untitled14.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"..\untitled14" -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\include" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.3588.1342.jom
"cl" ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ©
Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.
jom: C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\build-untitled14-Main-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\main.obj] Error 1
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc /Fddebug\untitled14.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"..\untitled14" -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\include" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Temp\mainwindow.obj.3588.1389.jom
"cl" ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ©
Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.
"cl" ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ©
Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc /Fddebug\untitled14.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"..\untitled14" -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\include" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\msvc2010_opengl\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_mainwindow.obj.3588.1404.jom
jom: C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\build-untitled14-Main-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\mainwindow.obj] Error 1
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Сообщения об ошибках надо приводить текстом, ибо нечитаемо.

Comment: Нажмите "Открыть изображение".

Comment: И еще раз: текст должен быть текстом.

Comment: Сделал. Помогите пожалуйста. На форуме пытался — не помогли.

Comment: Напишите cl.exe в обычной командной строке и покажите вывод.

Comment: Напротив поля `Отладчик`, `Компилятор` и т.д нажми `Управление`, затем `Добавить`, выбери нужный и укажи путь к нему. Уменя `Linux` - все работает.

Comment: Владимир Мартьянов, я ввел в командной строке Windows 7 — такой программы нет. Возможно я не понял смысл слов "обычной командной строке" .